# HTML datetime to PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, datetime

I am doing a to do list webpage using HTML, PHP and MySQL but I cannot submit the datetime to the database:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Sign Controller</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="update.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--MAIN CONTENT HERE-->
  <div class="container">
    <form id="controller" action="php/update.php" method="post">
      <h3>Sign display controller</h3>
      <h4>Event Controller</h4>
      <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="sign ID" type="text" name="sign_Name" tabindex="1" required autofocus/>
      </fieldset>
      <h5>Event Start</h5>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="time_eventStart" tabindex="2" required/>
      </fieldset>
      <h5>Event End</h5>
      <fieldset>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="time_eventEnd" tabindex="3" required/>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Event source" type="text" name="event_Source" tabindex="4"/>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <input placeholder="Idle source" type="text" name="idle_Source" tabindex="5"/>
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "projectSS";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sign_Name = $_POST["sign_Name"];
$event_Source = $_POST["event_Source"];
$idle_Source = $_POST["idle_Source"];
$time_eventStart = $_POST["time_eventStart"];
$time_eventEnd = $_POST["time_eventEnd"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO display (sign_Name,event_timeStart,event_timeEnd,event_Source,idle_Source)
VALUES ('$sign_Name','$time_eventStart','$time_eventEnd','$event_Source','$idle_Source')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm having a hard time to deal with the `datetime-local` type and I am new to programming so.

Comment: what error are you getting now?

Comment: mysql needs `YYYY-MM-DD` formatted date. Make sure either you are accepting date in that format or change format of accepted date to `YYYY-MM-DD` in php.

Comment: As `datetime-local` is not supported in IE, Firefox and Safari, you would need to so some serious data validation (you'd need to do that anyway...) and make sure it is in the correct format before you send it to the database. And you need to use prepared statements to avoid sql injection.

Comment: See about parametrised queries

Comment: i echo all the $_POST but receive nothing

Answer (score 1):

just change date time format as per mysql standard

if your column **datatype** is `date` used below

```
$time_eventStart = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["time_eventStart"]));
$time_eventEnd = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["time_eventEnd"]));
```

if your column **datatype** is `datetime` used below

```
$time_eventStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["time_eventStart"]));
$time_eventEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["time_eventEnd"]));
```

Comment: i use your solution but the value is wrong i enter 07/12/2017 12:00 AM but the database receives 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: just convert your date first then pass it to date function like this
$tmp = str_replace('/','-','07/12/2017 11:00 AM');
$time_eventStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($tmp));

Comment: it is ok if i use string but i want to use the datetime i select in the html $_POST["time_eventStart"]

Answer (score 0):

Change your query. Your query is not executing.

try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO display (sign_Name,event_timeStart,event_timeEnd,event_Source,idle_Source)
VALUES ('".$sign_Name."','".$time_eventStart."','".$time_eventEnd."','".$event_Source."','".$idle_Source."')";
```

Comment: This will result in exactly the same string as the OP already has. Unless you changed anything else apart from the string concatenation...

Comment: @jeroen that is also matter and variable inside the single quota is treated as name and will not take the value of that variable.

Comment: But the OP is using double quotes. The single quotes are inside and part of the string for the values in mysql.

Comment: @jeroen but inside of that there is single quota.

Comment: These are part of the string as literal quotes. The string itself is double-quoted so the variables will be expanded (if that's the correct term...).

Comment: @CodeLღver your answer is ok.

Comment: @jeroen some time variable has special character's then you need concatenation otherwise query error occurs

Comment: @BilalAhmed That's why you need a prepared statement or escaping. The resulting string here will be **exactly the same** as the one the OP has.

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thanks for your support. the resulting string will not be same. please just try once on your system.

Comment: They really are :-) Feel free to prove me wrong: https://eval.in/831429

Comment: the value is wrong i enter 07/12/2017 12:00 AM but the database receives 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @LDTuan You need to validate and re-format your data before you send it to the database.

Comment: i use : 
$time_eventStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["time_eventStart"]));
$time_eventEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["time_eventEnd"]));

Comment: @LDTuan and then what you got??

Comment: i received a wrong date and nothing in others i think the $_POST not getting any informations from my forms but i do not know how to fix this

Comment: @LDTuan check your datatype also in database

Comment: database is ok $_POST[] is not taking the value from the html form

Comment: @LDTuan are you posting the data using the javascript ajax??

Comment: well the problem is button type submit is not working i have to use input to make it work and got it now. tks for your help

Comment: @LDTuan ok , my pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$date = '2014-06-06 12:24:48';
echo date('d-m-Y (H:i:s)', strtotime($date));
```

and then save this.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> `datetime-local` it considered **24** hour format so if you select `07/12/2017 12:00 AM` it posted `2017-07-12T00:00`.
>
> In insert query just put posted value into your query. e.g.
>
> `$_POST['time_eventStart'].`
>
> Also if you print date-time to your input `echo` posted value. e.g.
>
> `<input type="datetime-local" name="time_eventStart" value="<?php echo $_POST['time_eventStart']; ?>" tabindex="2" required="" />`